# Does any one knows how to record an audio in testng

Tags: selenium, testng

I need to record **Audio** of a video available on a webpage.
And want to save it in

- .Mp3

  format.

Can anyone knows how to achieve it. Is there any external jars that need to be added to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 3rd party Package AtuTestRecorder.

```
     @BeforeTest public void setup() throws Exception 
    { 
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss"); 
        Date date = new Date(); //Created object of ATUTestRecorder //Provide path to store videos and file name format. 
        recorder = new ATUTestRecorder("E:\ScriptVideos\","TestVideo-"+dateFormat.format(date),false); //To start video recording. 
        recorder.start(); 
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.get("http://google.com/"); 
    }
```

```
@AfterTest public void Close() throws Exception 
{ 
    driver.quit(); 
    recorder.stop(); //To stop video recording. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation about this on the [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html). But here is the code you need :

```
TargetDataLine line;
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, 
    format); // format is an AudioFormat object
if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
    // Handle the error ... 

}
// Obtain and open the line.
try {
    line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(format);
} catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
    // Handle the error ... 
}
```

Comment: It's throwing an error on "format". I tried to give a variable in it's place still not working. nor .mp3 is working in its place

Comment: try with this : `AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat (16000, 8, 2, true, true);`

Answer (score -1):

You will require a programming language next to Selenium. Selenium can only check if audio is playing but cannot record audio.

I know that Java and C# can record audio and save in .Mp3 format.